# Description of enum in property grid

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I have a `Enum` as I use it in `Property Grid`.

```
 public enum Mye
    {
        [EnumItem("e 1", true, "This is e 1")]
        e1= 1,

        [EnumItem("e 2", true, "This is e 2")]
        e2= 2,
    }
```

Where am I supposed to see the **description**?

("This is e 1", "This is e 2")

Comment: EnumItem is a custom attribute created by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want [Enum Intellisense Display Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027046/enum-intellisense-display-attribute)

The description will be shown in a yellow tooltip when you are selecting 1 item from the items list of your enum.